# How do I select radio buttons in IE using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select radio buttons and select value in selectCls but facing problem with my code please help me on the same

Thanks in advance..

My VBA Code is:

```
Browser.document.getElementById("ddlCycleID").SelectCls = "Cycle 274 (21 Jun 2017 - 31 Jul 2017)" 
    Browser.document.getElementById("chkproc").Checked = True 
    Browser.document.getElementById("btnSubmit").Click
```

And HTML Source code is:

```
<td> 
<input value="chkproc" name="Module" type="radio" id="chkproc" checked="checked" tabindex="1" onclick="toggle(this)"> Processing Module 
<td> 


<td> 
<input value="chkquery" name="Module" type="radio" id="chkquery" tabindex="2" onclick="toggle(this)"> Other Modules 
<td> 


<td> 
<select name="ddlCycleID" id="ddlCycleID" tabindex="4" class="SelectCls" style="width:180px;"> 
<option value="Select Cycle">Select Cycle</option> 
<option value="274">Cycle 274 (21 Jun 2017 - 31 Jul 2017)</option> 
<option value="273">Cycle 273 (29 Jun 2017 - 29 Jun 2017)</option> 


</select> 
<td>
```

---

getting below error msg

Run-time error '424'

object required

in this code:

```
Browser.document.getElementById("ddlCycleID").SelectCls = "Cycle 274 (21 Jun 2017 - 31 Jul 2017)"

showing this "=""  when i place cursor on this code
```

Comment: Please explain what problems you are having - be specific. If you are getting errors, what are they and where do they appear?

Comment: Run-time error '424'

object required

Comment: Browser.document.getElementById("ddlCycleID").SelectCls = "Cycle 274 (21 Jun 2017 - 31 Jul 2017)"

showing this "=""  when i place cursor on this code